# Maven not copying some JAR to WEB-INF/lib

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have created a Web Project using Maven in Eclipse. I need pentaho library jar for the project and this is my dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
    <artifactId>libbase</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.8</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn:compile` or `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, it is downloading the JAR file in `maven_repo` local directory
I am using the following war plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>

        </plugin>
```

The problem is, when i run `mvn war:war` to create the war file, it is not copying the libbase-1.2.8.jar to the WEB-INF/lib folder. But it is copying all other JAR files. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `<optional>true</optional>`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism: Transitive Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) told us about the `optional` as the following:-

> **Optional dependencies** - If project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project Y can mark project Z as an **`optional dependency`**, using the **`"optional"`** element.
>
> When project X depends on project Y, X will depend only on Y and **not on Y's optional dependency Z**. The owner of project X may then explicitly add a dependency on Z, at her option. (***It may be helpful to think of optional dependencies as "excluded by default."***)

Then the `optional` dependency will not be included to our `WEB-INF/lib`.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Yes I have removed the `optional`